# Trigger to Prevent Users from Changing Opportunity Stage if Conditions Aren't Met

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I'm trying to write a trigger to prevent users from changing an opportunity stage if the following isn't met.

1. Opportunity doesn't have a contact with the role Champion.
2. Opportunity doesn't have an event with the type New Business Meeting.
3. Latest New Business Meeting doesn't have an RSM.
   I'm having trouble bulkifying the trigger. Here's my code.

Trigger

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before update) {
    if (Trigger.isBefore) {
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.New)
            {
                List<ID> OppID = New List<ID>();
                Opportunity oldOpp = Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.ID);
                if(opp.StageName == 'Discovery' && oldOpp.StageName == 'Scope' && opp.Link_to_Value_Pyramid__c != null){
                    OppID.add(opp.Id);
                    OpportunityHandler.stage2To3(Trigger.new);
                }
                if(opp.StageName == 'Discovery' && oldOpp.StageName == 'Scope' && opp.Link_to_Value_Pyramid__c == null){                                             
                    opp.addError('Unable to save. Please fill in the Link to Value Pyramid field');
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Trigger Handler

```
public class OpportunityHandler {
    public static void stage2To3(List<Opportunity> listOfNewOpportunities){
       Set<Id> oppsWithChampions = new Map<Id, SObject>(
            [SELECT Opportunity.Id
             FROM OpportunityContactRole 
             WHERE Role='Champion' AND Opportunity.Id IN :listOfNewOpportunities]).keySet();
        
      List<Event> oppsWithEvents = 
        [SELECT WhatId 
         FROM Event 
         WHERE Type = 'New Business Meeting'
         AND WhatId IN: oppsWithChampions];

      Map<Id, AggregateResult> maxEvents =  new Map<Id, AggregateResult> 
       ([SELECT WhatId Id, Max(ActivityDateTime) ActivityDate
         FROM Event
         WHERE Type = 'New Business Meeting'
         AND WhatId IN: oppsWithChampions
         GROUP BY WhatId]);

        Set<Id> whatIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (AggregateResult ar : [SELECT WhatId, Max(ActivityDateTime) ActivityDate
                           FROM Event
                           WHERE Type = 'New Business Meeting'
                           AND WhatId IN: oppsWithChampions
                           //AND ActivityDate = LAST_N_DAYS:35
                           GROUP BY WhatId]){
           whatIds.add((ID)ar.get('WhatId'));
        }

        List<Opportunity> oppNotUpdated  = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity 
                                           WHERE Id IN : listOfNewOpportunities
                                           AND Id NOT IN : whatIds]; 
       for(Opportunity o:listOfNewOpportunities){        
         for(Opportunity o:oppNotUpdated){
            o.addError('Please fill out the required information before changing the opportunity stage.');
        }
     }
  }
}
```

I have tried the following code but I get 'Invalid bind expression type of OpportunityContactRole does not match domain of foreign key'. How do I filter the listOfNewOpportunities to only include the ones that do not meet the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `List<SObject>` as a filter value in SOQL, it pulls the `Id` field. Since you are passing `List<OpportunityContactRole>`, this filter will *not* look for `What.Type = 'Opportunity'`, which is ostensibly what you are looking for. The basic problem is you need a `Set<Id> opportunityIds` or `List<Opportunity>`. I would opt for the former with:

```
Set<Id> opportunityIds = new Map<Id, SObject>([
    SELECT OpportunityId Id FROM OpportunityContactRole
    WHERE ...
]).keySet();
```

This approach can be a bit confusing for the uninitiated, but it doesn't do anything to complicated under the covers. The thing you need to understand to use it is that `Map<Id, SObject>` constructor can accept `AggregateResult`, and you can alias fields in aggregate queries to `Id`, which will then be used for the map key. This pattern uses governors very efficiently. Specifically it will be hard to beat on query rows and CPU time.

Once you have the `Set<Id>`, solving your current stumbling block should be a simple exercise.

---

On a minor tangent, I highly recommend moving *all* of your logic out of your trigger body and into classes instead. Basic trigger structure should look like:

```
public trigger MyObject on MyObject(/*events*/)
{
    MyObjectTriggerHandler handle = new MyObjectTriggerHandler(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap);
    switch on trigger.operationType
    {
        when BEFORE_INSERT { handle.beforeInsert(); }
        // AFTER_INSERT, BEFORE_UPDATE, AFTER_UPDATE, etc.
    }
}
```

And ideally your handler should do *nothing* but delegate to other service/filter layers.

```
public class MyHandler
{
    final List<MyObject__c> newRecords;
    final Map<Id, MyObject__c> oldMap;
    public MyHandler(List<MyObject> newRecords, Map<Id, SObject> oldMap)
    {
        this.newRecords = newRecords;
        this.oldMap = oldMap;
    }
    
    public void beforeInsert()
    {
        MyValidationService.addError(
            MyFilterService.isInvalidBecauseXYZ(newRecords);
        );
    }
    
    public void beforeUpdate()
    {
        MyValidationService.addError(
            MyFilterService.isInvalidBecauseXYZ(newRecords, oldMap);
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code and I'm no longer getting that error but when I add AND Id NOT IN : (ID)maxEvents.get('Id'). I get Incompatible types since an instance of AggregateResult is never an instance of Id.

Comment: The code is no longer throwing errors. I just need to test to see if it's working as expected. Thanks for your help. @Adrian

Comment: The error in the trigger is working but the one in the handler is thrpwing OpportunityTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors (). How can make mine work?

Comment: Either you mixed up the events or did the assignment differently than listed above.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code in Developer Console so it's the same but when I run it I get the error. I was reading that the addError message is is applicable only on records that is part of trigger context variable means Trigger.old and Trigger.new. It means We can use this method only in triggers and only on Trigger.old and Trigger.new context variable. I'm not sure how I would get around that. I added a debug on oppNotUpdated and there's data in there.

Comment: Yes it only works on trigger context records. You won't be able to test `addError` behavior directly via `Execute Anonymous`. You'll have to do DML and inspect the results of it.

Comment: I'm testing by changing the status in the UI and not Execute Anonymous.

Comment: I updated the code so that the trigger passes the trigger.new as opposed to the Ids and I added for(Opportunity o:listOfNewOpportunities){ and I'm getting the custom error now. @Adrian